# Объединить подложу карты в Unity2d из множества случайных спрайтов в один

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я еще начинающий в Unity и пытаюсь сделать пошаговую игру 2D. Карта, сгенерированная при старте игры случайно из 1200 шестиугольников(Prefab), выглядит довольно громоздко. Есть идея занести все данные сетки в отдельный объект, а спрайты создавать как один, склеенный из всех в начале игры(карта не будет меняться в процессе). Единственный найденный способ - создать текстуру из пикселей спрайтов, но переносить по пикселям получается еще дольше. Возможно в Unity есть еще что-то для этого? Или же все варианты склейки спрайтов будут более громоздкими чем просто отрисовать 1200 спрайтов? Буду рад, если подскажете куда копать и стоит ли.

Comment: 1200 спрайтов генерируются при запуске? Или сгенерированы в каком-то стороннем ПО и просто добавлены в проект?

Comment: Все верно. Объекты(GameObject) со спрайтами генерируются случайно при каждом запуске игры в заданной сетке координат методом Instantiate(). Спрайты заранее прописаны в вариациях шестиугольников(prefabs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У обоих вариантов свои но.

---

Сгенерировать текстуру можно. Точнее текстуры, лучше всё-таки её распилить на сектора. `Texture2D.Apply` должен быть только один, это самая грузная операция. Так-же нужно не забывать уничтожать сгенерированные текстуры, кода они уже не нужны (например смена уровня), чтобы они не висели в памяти `Destroy(YourGenericTexture)`!

Тут ещё важно знать правило выделения памяти под размер картинки. Память выделяется под размеры 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 и т.д. То-есть
картинка 600x600 в памяти займёт столько-же как 1024x1024. Размеры сектора должны это учитывать.

Вот только проблема в шестигранности. При нанесении пикселей они будут пересикаться и нужно, что бы новый шестигранник не перезатерал тестуру прозрачными пиксели, спрайт то квадратный и условия наложения будут существенно тормозить процесс генерации текстур. Но есть вариант, после того, как уровень готов, сгенерировать всё заранее и в итоговой игре использовать заготовки, тогда время генерации значения не имеет, но с тем же успехом это можно сделать и в фотошопе, поскольку ставить это на рельсы для начинающего трудновато.

---

Вариант с 1тайл-1спрайт тоже имеет право на жизнь. Но тысячи это конечно перебор. В данном случае объекты с спрайтами не должны содержать вообще никакой игровой логики, игра должна работать, да же если их нет. Это нужно для того, чтобы поделить карту на чанки и иметь возможность удалять и спавнить визуальное представление чанка (спрайты) которые попадают или выходят из поля зрения камеры при её движении. В этом случае игровая карта может быть невироятных размеров, но это не выльется в миллионы объектов на сцене. Для этого тоже некий навык нужен.

Например в том-же майнкравте вся карта состоит из чанков размером 16x16x256 блоков.

---

Начал программировать, молодец, добро пожаловать в ад. Мне кажется с обоих способов тебе охота на стенку полезть, но ещё есть какой-то [Tilemap-Hexagonal](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Hexagonal.html). Ни сразу о нём вспомнил, никогда не пользовался родными `Tilemap` юнити и ничего про них сказать не могу, но скорее всего тебе самое оно .

Comment: Tilemaps, пожалуй, действительно очень хорошо подходят для такого рода игр. На них наверное и остановлюсь. Спасибо за наводку.